# How do I DD over the network to an external HD?

Tags: networking, dd

I'm trying to clone a hard drive on my raspberry pi which is on the same network to an external harddrive of the computer I'm currently on. However I'm having issues piping the command correctly. I've tried:

```
ssh user@hostip "dd if=/dev/sda" | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc
```

But the prompts for the sudo and the ssh connection stack together.

Answer (score 8):

Using netcat - no unneeded load on your CPU if you're not concerned about privacy (i.e. your home network is yours really)

On your host, run

`cat /dev/sda | nc -n ipaddr 10000`

where `ipaddr` is IP address of your PI

On your PI, run

`nc -l 10000 >/dev/sdc`

All commands are to be run as root. OpenBSD netcat is assumed to be your `nc` version there (can be found in LibreSSL), but others should work too.

Answer (score 5):

Some simple workarounds without changing your command line:

- Use key authentication (with `ssh-agent` if the key file is password-protected) instead of password authentication for SSH. It's usually a good idea anyway.
- Use SSH's connection multiplexing to first open a connection (e.g. `ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -M -f sleep 999999`), then run the copy in a slave connection, which doesn't require authentication. See [Get indication of ssh command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93563/get-indication-of-ssh-command/93647#93647) for an example.
- Run `sudo true` just before running this command. By default sudo caches the information that it's verified your password for 15 minutes (at least if you do it on the same terminal, that depends on the configuration).

If you really must type both passwords in the command due to an unusually restrictive configuration, you can use a named pipe to separate the commands:

```
mkfifo pipe
ssh user@hostip cat /dev/sda >pipe
# and in another terminal
sudo sh -c 'cat >/dev/sdc' <pipe
```

Also, use `cat` instead of `dd`, it's [faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd) and [more reliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/why-does-dd-from-dev-random-give-different-file-sizes).

Comment: I am indeed using a private key, but I wasn't aware of ssh-agent - cool stuff! I am interested in using cat though based on the links you posted. Do you have any recommended reading on backing up HDs with cat?

Comment: @SHiLLySiT `cat` is simple to use: it copies its input to its output. That's what you were doing with `dd`, only slower.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need a bit-for-bit copy of the entire remote disk?  e.g. for digital forensics?

If not, if you just need a copy of the partitions and the data on them, you can save a lot of time and transfer bandwidth by:

1. copying the partition table, e.g. with `sfdisk`.

For example:

```
ssh user@hostip sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdc
```

or in two steps with a tempfile:

```
ssh user@hostip sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > /tmp/sda.txt
sudo sfdisk /dev/sdc < /tmp/sda.txt
```

2. using `partclone` to clone only the parts of the filesystem that are currently in use, ignoring all the empty space and deleted files etc.

For example:

```
ssh user@hostip sudo partclone.ext4 -c -s /dev/sda1 -o - | 
    sudo partclone.ext4 -r -s - -o /dev/sdc1
```

`partclone` supports all common and some uncommon fileystems used on Linux (ext2/3/4, btrfs, xfs, etc) and Windows (NTFS, FAT).

[partclone](http://partclone.org/) is packaged for most distros, including debian.  `sfdisk` is part of the `util-linux` package.

You still need to solve the ssh / sudo issue, but @Gilles has given a good answer for that.

The easiest way to eliminate the password prompts is to do all of this as root (`sudo -i` to get a root shell), so you don't need to preface every command with `sudo`, and to (as root) run `ssh-copy-id hostip` to install root@localhost's ssh key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on hostip.  Then you can run:

```
ssh hostip sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdc
ssh hostip partclone.ext4 -c -s /dev/sda1 -o - | 
    partclone.ext4 -r -s - -o /dev/sdc1
```

If you're running ssh-agent, you'll only have to type in the passphrase for root's key once at the most (or not at all if you've used it previously).

Comment: could you detail a bit more about sfdisk? how do you use it?